# yii switch template for specific request

Tags: php, yii

I have a controller called `Basic` that deals with multiple requests:

```
array('allow','actions' => array('index', 'maintenance',
 'error', 'page', 'login', 'logout', 'lostPassword', 
'resetPassword', 'signup', 'activate'),
```

and in `actions()` page is rendered by  CviewAction

```
 'page' => array(
                'class' => 'CViewAction',
            ),
```

I wish to use a different layout for only requests that involve page/

How can I say if request is `page` from controller 'Basic' don't use main to render layout instead use "X"?

Something like:

```
public function actionIndex() {
 //if incoming_request uses "page" use layout home.
    $this->layout = 'home';
```

Comment: I think in controllers you have `init()` method, you can put your logic there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put it in the respective action. In your case, this is `actionPage`:

```
public function actionPage() {
    $this->layout = 'home';
```